# Fazer combinação de times em SQL sem repetição

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia,

Tenho um banco de dados aqui com as tabelas abaixo, e queria gerar uma tabela
com a combinação dos times cadastrados

> ```
> Time
> ------
> Time A
> Time B
> Time C
> Time D
> ```

A tabela final ficaria assim:

> ```
> TABELA 1 | TABELA 2
> TIME A   | TIME B
> TIME B   | TIME C
> TIME C   | TIME D
> TIME A   | TIME C
> TIME D   | TIME A
> ```

O comando que testei foi esse:

```
SELECT a1.nome_time, a2.nome_time 
FROM times a1, times a2
WHERE a1.nome_time < a2.nome_time;
```

como poderia modificar este comando para que a tabela não se repita na segunda coluna?

Comment: Reveja sua tabela final e verifique se é este mesmo o resultado desejado.

Comment: o que daria para fazer seria um for em uma linguagem de fora, para poder pegar um numero e atribuir ao ID desse time sendo que esse numero nao foi repetido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tente algo desse gênero

```
SELECT a1.nome_time, a2.nome_time 
FROM times a1, times a2
WHERE a1.nome_time < a2.nome_time and a1.nome_time <> a2.nome_time;
```

Comment: Se a condição a1.nome_time < a2.nome_time for atendida então certamente a1.nome_time <> a2.nome_time será verdadeiro. Douglas poderia explicar melhor qual o resultado desejado.

Comment: Realmente foi erro meu em achar essa conclusão, não compreendi muito

Comment: Não necessariamente Douglas.

Comment: Melhorei um pouco a tabela aqui e analisando o código acrescentei no select acima ORDER BY RAND (); Conforme tinha avisado que este é só um teste que estou fazendo para gerar tabelas de jogos, a segunda coluna não está mais repetindo os registros.

Answer (score 0):

Use o distinct, o sql ficaria assim:

"SELECT Distinct a1.nome_time, a2.nome_time 
FROM times a1, times a2
WHERE a1.nome_time < a2.nome_time;"